# Android fails to mkdirs()

Tags: java, android, storage, android-file

I know that similar questions has been already asked, but I have already tried to do what I read there.

I am writing an app that need to access and create some files, and in my `onCreate()` method I call the `directoryMaker()` method:

```
 static final String externalPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()+"/MyFolder"; //This is a global variable

 private void directoryMaker (){
    if(externalIsMounted()){
        File external = new File(externalPath);
        if(!external.exists()){
           if(external.mkdirs()){
               Log.i("GalleryActivity", "Folder created");
           }
            else{
               Log.e("GalleryActivity", "Folder not created");
           }

        }
    }
}

private boolean externalIsMounted(){
    return Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
}
```

This is my Manifest (at least the relative part):

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Running it gives the "Folder not created" error: I don't know what can be wrong at this point.

PS: Sorry for my bad English, isn't my first language.

EDIT 1
The entire *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="course.exercise.dailyselfy"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
            android:name="a.b.MyApp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Where have you put them in the AndroidManifest? Can you please show us the full manifest?

Comment: In the <manifest> tag, anyway I've added it in the question. Also: why the question has been downvotated? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following constructor instead of coding the path yourself

```
File external = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyFolder");
```

then call the `mkdir()` method.
You don't need `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission as `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` implicitly uses it.

Comment: Tried, but it gives me the same problem. Also thanks for the permission's information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String dirPath = root.toString() +  "/Pictures/Your folder/";
    File dir = new File(dirPath);

    if (!dir.exists()) {
       dir.mkdirs();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First let me excuse, I understood how stupid my question was: I am new to Android programming, so...

Anyway the code hadn't any issues, but I was running it on the AndroidStudio emulator and I had to give to the app the permissions in the **Setting**->**App** menu.